# limit as x approaches infinity from the left (Notation)

Tags: limits, notation, infinity

This question doesn't involve a specific problem, instead focuses on notation. With limits that approach infinity, is it incorrect to say that the limit approaches infinity from the positive/negative direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that you are talking about limits of *real* quantities (like in a usual calculus class).  Then $\infty = +\infty$ can only be approached from the negative direction, and $-\infty$ only from the positive direction. So, for example, writing $x \to \infty^-$ would be redundant, and $x \to \infty^+$ wouldn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

So, if it is approacing $+ \infty$ then it can only approach it from the **negative** side. If it is approaching $- \infty$ then it can only approach it from the **positive** side.

This is due to the fact that when approaching any value, you have to traverse along finite values. Anything in between, and not including, $- \infty$ and $+ \infty$ is considered to be a finite value. So if you were to lie outside of the interval $(- \infty, + \infty)$ you are inevitably dealing with non-finite values which has no place in mathematical expressions, except for comparing cardinalities.